# How to install Altera USB master driver for Windows 8 (64 bit)?

Tags: driver, intel-fpga, quartus

I am trying to connect Altera Stratix 4 board with my PC in which Quartus 11.0 is per-installed. But my PC is not detecting USB JTAG connection from the board.

What I am guessing is that, this problem is because drivers are not supporting window 8 64 bit version. Am I right ? How can I rectify this problem ?

I tried Googling, but nothing is helping me. Help me please.

Edit: In list of drivers\others USB Blaster is showing, I right clicked and tried to install driver for the same. But it is not working. I think the problem is that USB Blaster driver is not working. How can I rectify this problem?

Edit 2: Error window [image]

Comment: Can you s ee anything in the list of USB devices connected to your PC when you connect the board? I had lots of problem with it when I had a Win8 laptop, but then I moved to Ubuntu instead. What is the version of Altera you have installed on your PC is it 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @FarhadA USB blaster is not installed or failed, I think. Warning symbol in list of USB devices connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering" normally means that the driver isn't signed in a manner that Windows 8 will accept. It probably means the driver hasn't been signed as per [Signing a Driver for Public Release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh967734%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it could also mean it's been tampered with.

You can follow instructions such as [Disabling Driver Signature on Windows 8](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/disabling-driver-signature-on-windows-8/disabling-signed-driver-enforcement-on-windows-8) if you're happy to disable driver signing on your system and are confident the driver came from a valid source. If you do that of course pay careful attention to the message "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software" in the future if you see it for drivers from a less reliable source.

While I haven't used that particular Altera programming tool many embedded programming devices seem to have a considerable lag until they have driver support for new operating systems. For legacy USB devices that are end of life where driver updates aren't likely you'll also find that running older operating systems such as Windows XP within a virtual machine may be another option worth looking at.